# How do I convert this array type, which I want to be a float64 type

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Because there's a pair of single quotes outside the array. I always report errors when I process data, and I want to convert it to another type.

arr.dtype = 'float64'  , That doesn't work

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array('[1,2,3,4]')
>>> arr
array('[1,2,3,4]', dtype='<U9')
>>> arr.shape
()
>>> arr.size
1
>>> print(arr[0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: too many indices for array
>>> arr.dtype
dtype('<U9')

# I want to convert it to the following type
>>> arr1 = np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> arr1
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> arr1.shape
(4,)
>>> arr1.size
4
>>> arr.dtype
dtype('<U9')
>>>
```

What should I do？thanks

## P.S.

This is a problem in a movie recommendation system project.U_vec is the array in question.

```py
    print(userprofile.array)
    u_vec = np.array(userprofile.array)
    print('uu:',u_vec)
    Umatrix = cache.get('umatrix')
    print(Umatrix.shape,'--',u_vec.dtype)
    movieslist = cache.get('titles')
```

Comment: Just don't put _a pair of single quotes_ outside the array if that's messing up with you.

Comment: You mean `x = x.astype(np.float64)`  ?

Comment: This is the type of data that I'm pulling out, and I didn't mean to use it.

Comment: >>> arr2 = arr.astype(np.float64)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[1,2,3,4]'
>>>

Comment: What's the output of `userprofile.array`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'[1,2,3,4]'` is a string, but `[1,2,3,4]` is a list. In the first example you're creating a `numpy` array from a string, which numpy isn't able to process. But it can process the latter.

If you really don't have a choice of not using anything other than a string, and you're sure that the string will be a syntactically correct python list, then you can use `exec` method to create a numpy array out of it:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> exec('arr = np.array({})'.format('[1,2,3,4]'))
>>> arr
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> arr.shape
(4,)
>>> arr.size
4
>>> print(arr[0])
1
>>> arr.dtype
dtype('int64')
```

As the string contains integers instead of floats, so numpy will create an array with dtype of `int64`, but if you want it in `float64`, you can do the following to create the array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> exec('arr = np.array({}).astype(np.float64)'.format('[1,2,3,4]'))
>>> arr
array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
>>> arr.dtype
dtype('float64')
```

And this will create an array with type `float64`.

Comment: Thank you but why am I using it the wrong way.>>> arr5 = "'[1,2,3,4]'"
>>> arr5
"'[1,2,3,4]'"
>>> print(arr5)
'[1,2,3,4]'
>>> exec('arr3 = np.array({})'.format(arr5))
>>> arr3
array('[1,2,3,4]', dtype='<U9')

Comment: Why are you putting an extra pair of `"` now? They weren't in the original question anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```py
    >>> import ast
    >>> import numpy as np
    >>> arr9 = '[1,2,3,4]'
    >>> arr9 = ast.literal_eval(strArr)
    >>> arr9
    [1, 2, 3, 4]
    >>> type(arr9)
    <class 'list'>
    >>> arr = np.array(arr9,float64)
    >>> arr
    [1,2,3,4]
```